# Differential equation problem!

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I've found an answer to a question, which is apparently incorrect but I have no idea why.

"Find the solution of the differential equation that satisfies the given initial condition."

$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{2t^2+sec^2(t)}{2u}, u(0) = -3$

$\int2u.du = \int(2t+sec^2(t) )dt$

$\frac{2u^2}{2} = \frac{2t^2}{2}+tan(t) + C$

$u^2 = t^2+tan(t)+C$

$u = \sqrt{t^2+tan(t)+C}$

$u(0) = \sqrt{0^2+tan(0)+C}$ = -3

$=>\sqrt{C} = -3$

$=> C = 9$

So the solution is $u =  \sqrt{t^2+tan(t)+9}$, yes?

Apparently my answer is wrong but I can't for the life of me see how.

Any indication of my mistake would be much appreciated?

Comment: You didn't multiply $\tan (t)$ by $2$ and since you are getting a negative number from the square root you should put a $-$ in front of it. Convention says the square root is positive otherwise.

Comment: Also, $\sqrt{9} = -3?$ That is wrong.

Comment: @Sabyasachi you can take the negative root $\sqrt{9} = \pm 3$

Comment: That original equation is correct?  Looks like you lost an exponent on your $t$ when you cross-multiplied.

Comment: @ruler501 $\sqrt 9 = 3$, period.

Comment: @ruler501 no we can *not* take the "negative root". How many times do I have to tell people that $\sqrt{}$ is NOT the inverse of $x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was that you didn't put in a $\pm$ in front of the square root. From there the solution should've gone as

$u = \pm\sqrt{t^2+\tan(t)+C}$

$u(0) = \pm\sqrt{0^2+\tan(0)+C}$ = -3

$\implies -\sqrt{C} = -3$

$\implies C = 9$

$u =  -\sqrt{t^2+\tan(t)+9}$

Comment: Why would he multiply $\tan t$ by $2$?

Comment: You multiplied both sides by $2$ to clear the denominator on the left. Wait nvm I didn't notice the numerators had a 2 in them  also.

Comment: I had just seen it as $\frac{u^2}{2}$ instead of $\frac{2u^2}{2}$

Comment: I'll wait for him to clarify the original equation before I edit then.

Comment: @ruler501 Yes I got the right answer now. It was simply the lack of negative symbol.

Comment: @Wolff you should fix the original question to be consistent. Your first line doesn't go to your seconds since the first has $2t^2$ and your second has $2t$